# EWM: Function or program for changing goods received date

Tags: abap, sap-ewm

Does someone know a function, class, method or a report to change the goods receipt date in SAP EWM?

I have already searched with google and in SAP EWM system. But without success!

Any help would be very appreciated. :)

Best regards.

Alexander

Comment: Did You search in SE37 ? BAPI_PO_CHANGE or something should do the job, if I rememnber correctly.

Comment: I have tried it, but it does not exist in the EWM-System. Do you have other suggestions? Thanks :)